# Locally compact group

Tags: locally-compact-groups

I want/need to learn about locally compact groups in rigorous way. Mainly to completely understand Tate's thesis/Weil's basic number theory. Could you recommend a text or lecture note which would explain in detail? I can't seem to find elementary text for it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at Folland's "A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis"?

Comment: I will have a look there. Also I seem to find

http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/theses/leahy/thesis.pdf

use ful

Comment: For number theory, slightly less generality is perfect: one wants to look at profinite groups (for Galois groups - these are compact) and locally compact abelian groups (for additive and multiplicative Haar measures on local fields and adeles/ideles).

Comment: The book of Markus Stroppel "Locally compact groups". It contains the most important fact on locally compact groups.